# How can I place a normal HTML word between <> tags?

Tags: html

A very weird question in comparison with what is asked on this site generally, but:

I want to place a normal word between the <> tags. The output should be 
<Random Word>. Of course a browser sees this as a HTML tag like `<div>` and doesn't display anything.

Strange enough I can't find a way to do this anywhere to my feeling is the solution is very easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should encode the signs

```
&lt;Random Word&gt;
```

Giving

<Random Word>

Comment: Thanks! u da real mvp